# Why does "Your Ad Could Go Here" state that the Orange Revolution lasted for three weeks?

Tags: short-stories, historical-context, ukrainian-language, your-ad-could-go-here, oksana-zabuzhko

The Orange Revolution protests were called for on November 21, 2004 in response to election fraud in their 2004 Presidential election. Eventually, the Supreme Court ordered a re-vote on December 26, 2004, and Wikipedia lists the protests as continuing into January.

However, *An Album for Gustav* repeatedly refers to the Orange Revolution as lasting three weeks. For example,

> When people ask me this question and I try to answer, every time I feel like I come up against a solid wall inside myself, a profound lack of desire to explain anything, muddling in my inadequate English, to mutter that hard is not quite the right word, and it doesn't really fit what we experienced during **those three weeks.**

Why the discrepancy?